# Multiple query on same table

Tags: php, mysql

This is a part of big query that are generated dynamically depending on the on post params ...

there is a table user_params

```
id |  user_id | param_id | param_value 
--------------------------------------
1  | 5        |  2       | audi
--------------------------------------
2  | 5        |  3       | a4
--------------------------------------
3  | 5        |  4       | silver
--------------------------------------
4  | 7        |  2       | audi
--------------------------------------
5  | 7        |  3       | q3
--------------------------------------
6  | 8        |  2       | ford
--------------------------------------
7  | 8        |  3       | fiesta
--------------------------------------
```

I want to extract all 'user_id' where 'param_id' = 1 , 'param_value' = 'audi' , 'param_id' = 3 , 'param_value' = 'a4'

So in this instance my result should contain `id` rows 1,2,4,5,7.

What is the best way considering that this table has more than 50K entries ?

It's an InnoDB table.

+++ Now I see there is a html form with multiselect fields for these table. 
"Give me all users (user_id) who drive audi (a4 or q3) or VW (passat) which are silver color".

I'm testing solutions that you've written.

Comment: There really isn't enough info to go on here. What indexes, if any, do you have on your table? Would it be an option to change the table, what storage engine are you using (depending on the engine, the _"optimal query"_ might look very different -> innoDB vs ndbcluster, for example)

Comment: It's InnoDB.  Consider it impossible to change the base now . I inherited this code :(

Comment: @DiveboDiving would you update your question with "edit" to show that it is InnoDB etc? cheers

Comment: @DiveboDiving: You've asked for the best way to go about this query: try some of the suggestions, and use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` to see which query performs best

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem  Of course I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've actually gone ahead and created a test table based on what you've posted here as example data, here's the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `param_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `param_value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Next, here's how I populated it with the data

```
INSERT INTO `test`
(
  `user_id`,
  `param_id`,
  `param_value`
)
VALUES
(5,2, 'audi'),
(5,3, 'a4'),
(5,4, 'silver'),
(7,2, 'audi'),
(7,3, 'q3'),
(8,2, 'ford'),
(8,3, 'fiesta');
```

Then, here are the various queries I've tried:

```
/** using OR + DISTINCT **/
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM test
WHERE (param_id = 1 AND param_value = 'audi')
   OR (param_id = 3 AND param_value = 'a4')
   OR (param_id = 4 AND param_value = 'silver')

/** using OR + GROUP BY **/
SELECT user_id
FROM test
WHERE (param_id = 1 AND param_value = 'audi')
   OR (param_id = 3 AND param_value = 'a4')
   OR (param_id = 4 AND param_value = 'silver')
GROUP BY user_id


/** Using tripple join **/
SELECT
    t1.user_id
FROM
    test AS t1,
    test AS t2,
    test AS t3
WHERE
    t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t2.user_id=t3.user_id AND
    t1.param_id = 2 AND t1.param_value = 'audi' AND
    t2.param_id = 3 AND t2.param_value = 'a4' AND
    t3.param_id = 4 AND t3.param_value = 'silver'

/** JOIN with ON clause instead of WHERE **/
SELECT
    t1.user_id
FROM
test AS t1
JOIN
test AS t2
    ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
JOIN
test AS t3
    ON t3.user_id = t1.user_id
WHERE
    t1.param_id = 2 AND t1.param_value = 'audi' AND
    t2.param_id = 3 AND t2.param_value = 'a4' AND
    t3.param_id = 4 AND t3.param_value = 'silver'
```

All of these queries produce the same result. However, the way the result is obtained is very different indeed, which shows in the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` output, which you can easily see for yourself now by running all of these queries, and prepending `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`, because I'm just too lazy to paste all of the output here ATM

What you should see is that the `JOIN` queries all show up as a join-type `ALL`, meaning the entire table is scanned (3 times over), which the `rows` count reflects, each JOIN affects all 7 rows (so 21 in total).
Compare that to the alternative, `JOIN`-less queries, which only have to scan 7 rows, and I think it's fairly likely that joins probably aren't the answer in this case.

Comment: This is a good answer, +1 for making your own testing table! ha.

Comment: the `param_id` for the model is `2`, not `1` ! So the first two queries should be written with `WHERE (param_id = 2 AND param_value = 'audi')`. As you rewrite the queries with the correct `param_id` you'll notice they will return both user_id 5 and 7. So the first two queries don't get the expected result.

Comment: @Paolo: Indeed, I seem to have made a mistake, I'll see what I can do about that, and edit my answer later on (right now, I have to get some work done first)

Comment: That is because of the `OR` , so you would need to use a `AND` , and in this case I don't see how you would get a reliable result without a join...

Answer (score 2):

You have to perform multiple joins on the same table.

One way to do it is like this

```
SELECT
    t1.user_id
FROM
    thetable AS t1,
    thetable AS t2,
    thetable AS t3
WHERE
    t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t2.user_id=t3.user_id AND
    t1.param_id = 1 AND t1.param_value = 'audi' AND
    t2.param_id = 3 AND t2.param_value = 'a4' AND
    t3.param_id = 4 AND t3.param_value = 'silver'
```

This is equivalent as using `JOIN` statements, but it's just to give the idea.

Of course the query have to be extended or reduced depending on how many parameters your're checking (3 in the example case).

If all the fields are indexed the query should run quite fast on 50K records.

Comment: While the question example doesn't need this depth of answer, I think this is the answer the OP is most looking for, basically saying that to do multiple table queries, load the table multiple times. +1

Comment: Wow, joining the table onto itself three times over... Is that _really_ better than using an `OR` in the query? seriously?

Comment: The _comma operator_ ***is*** a `JOIN` as far as mysql is concerned, to quote the docs: _"`INNER JOIN` and `,` (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition"_ , [see here for details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: That's what I meant by writing *Another way is using JOIN statements, but it's just to give the idea.* - Regarding the previous comment I don't think you can solve the problem using the `OR` operator and without JOINs.

Comment: @Paolo: What you wrote seems to suggest that an _alternative_ to the comma operator would be to use `JOIN`, whereas the comma operator is short for `INNER JOIN` in this case. Write `JOIN` or comma's, both do the same thing: they join the same table onto itself 3 times, effectively forcing MySQL to search through 150K records, instead of 50K (probably resulting in the use of a temp table and all that. Use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` to see what the difference is between your tripple join and a `WHERE` clause with a couple of `OR`'s

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : Usin a `OR` wouldn't do the expected effect. A `AND` would be what is needed but that would anyway require that all values are fields of the same record while here it's all different records. The table would need to be "flattened"  before you can simply use `AND` and `OR` Statements on it

Comment: Oh, BTW: no joins, just a single `WHERE (param_id = 1 AND param_value = 'audi') OR (param_id = 3 AND param_value = 'a4') OR (param_id = 4 AND param_value = 'silver')` there's really not much too it. Use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate `user_id` values

Comment: I agree to the first part. Regarding the triple join I don't see other ways to do what the OP asked, but I don't see performance issues as he/she has 50K records.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem this: `WHERE (param_id = 1 AND param_value = 'audi') OR (param_id = 3 AND param_value = 'a4') OR (param_id = 4 AND param_value = 'silver')` will return all the users with an "audi" along with all the users with a car model "a4' along with all the users with a silver car. So I don't think that's what the OP asked. He wants only the users with and "Audi", model "a4", color "silver".

Comment: @Paolo: Have you actually tried it? Because I have, and it just returns user_id 5. Nothing more, nothing less. The result is the same as yours, without the joins

Comment: @Bartdude: Check my answer, because your claim of a `WHERE` + `OR` clause not producing the same results is just plain wrong. Just re-read you comment, and think about what you say that a tripple join is better than a single table, because that single table needs to be _"flattened"_, and a tripple join doesn't. That, to me at least, just doesn't make any sense

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes, I've tried it but i get both user 5 and 7 because they both have "audi" so they both match the `WHERE` clause. Unfortunately user 7 has not a mode "a4" but "q3" so it's an extra unwanted user.

Comment: @Paolo: In that case, check my answer (I've added the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements) to show what data I've used to test the queries on, because if you got different results, chances are one of us is missing something

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem there's a typo in you answer. `param_id` for car model is `2`, not `1`. There are actually no records with `param_id = 1` in the table.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : I'll admit it when you get all and only users id that have a silver audi A4 without using a join... As such I don't see how this would be possible but you might indeed be better than me with queries so I would learn something :-) Keep in mind incomplete test data might not show exact result...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to speed things up you can ADD indexes to the affected columns. But actually no DBM should have a problem with 50k data sets. It's not that much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the term `'param_id' = 1 AND 'param_value' = 'audi' AND 'param_id' = 3 AND 'param_value' = 'a4'` would always be false, so I just assume you want to use `(param_id = 1 AND param_value = 'audi') OR (param_id = 3 AND 'param_value' = 'a4')`

In that case the query could be like: `select distinct user_id where (param_id = 1 AND param_value = 'audi') OR (param_id = 3 AND 'param_value' = 'a4')`

Comment: Assuming that the query should yield a list of search results, you can't go ahead and assume that you can _"know"_ what `param_id` goes with which `param_value` a series of `OR`'s would be inefficient but probably better, in which case, the shortest `WHERE` clause would be `WHERE param_id IN(1, 3) OR param_value IN ('audi', 'a4')`

Comment: I agree. I just assumed that the `param_id` = 1 stands for the car maker and `param_id` = 3 stands for the car type.

Comment: Here we are a problem if I search by color ( param_id = 4 ) and then we will return all vehicles that are for example red  because the OR.

Comment: @DiveboDiving: That was just a suggestion, you can fine-grain it further, but my thinking was that if you wanted to query for search results, you want to show every possible match for every _"keyword"_ used. If you google for _"red audi a4"_, the results will include red pieces of A4 paper, or green audi R8's all the same

Comment: Ok, now I understand the question better. If you want to find only the combinations like red Audi A4, then the suggestion from @Paolo is the best option I can think of.

Better would be to redesign the data model and to store the color, brand, type etc. of one car (user_id) in specific columns of the same table row and get rid of the column `param_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any values if you're trying it with AND everytime. What it does is he tries to get a user_id with a param_id of 1 and has a value of audi and also a param_id of 3 and also a param_value of a4. You need to try it with OR and i dont see any param_id of 1 so make sure that one exists. If i understand your question correctly you need to do something like

```
SELECT user_id FROM tablename WHERE 'param_id' = 1 AND 'param_value' = 'audi' OR 'param_id' = 3 AND 'param_value' = 'a4'
```

Comment: this would return unwanted `user_id`s

Comment: The question was that he wanted all user_id's.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below where condition in query

```
where param_id in (1,3) && param_value in ('audi','a4')
```